# SAML SSO with IS, logout, for the saml request done with sectoken

Tags: wso2-identity-server

How to do logout for the saml sso where the auth is performed by sectoken , and not from any filter ?

Comment: is the sectoken you are referring is the one used for basic auth requestpath authentication?

Comment: @farasath, yes. Looking into the source code it looks like HttpSession, mapParams are removed, along with invalidate the sessionIndex.
Tried to create the LogoutRequestObject & done a http-post as url param, IS is not recognizing the request